# Shopify GraphQL CustomerAccessToken

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify, graphql

I'm currently customising a Shopify App, allowing users to edit their profiles.

I am using the Shopify Webfront API with GraphQL, specifically the "CustomerUpdate" mutation:
https://help.shopify.com/api/storefront-api/reference/mutation/customerupdate

Calling the GraphQL end point using jQuery AJAX.

However, the method requires a CustomerAccessToken parameter but I am unsure how is this generated; the Customer Shopify Liquid class does not have it, 
and the main searches for Shopify CustomerAccessTokens end up revolving around Shopify API Tokens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TLDR: Unsure how to generate the CustomerAccessToken for the GraphQL CustomerUpdate mutation.

Cheers
Xavier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the [getting started link](https://help.shopify.com/api/storefront-api/getting-started) on the API documentation. Follow the instructions for the type of API you will be using.

You can get a storefront access token by creating a private app or by using the REST API.

Customer Access tokens are [created](https://help.shopify.com/api/storefront-api/reference/mutation/customeraccesstokencreate#interactive-example), [deleted](https://help.shopify.com/api/storefront-api/reference/mutation/customeraccesstokendelete/) or [renewed](https://help.shopify.com/api/storefront-api/reference/mutation/customeraccesstokenrenew/) through a API calls.

In general, you would send the same username and email to the create access token that you send to create customer. You would then use that access token to update the customer.

Comment: Hi Alexander, 
Thank you so much for the prompt response.
It is what I needed.

But would you have any idea how could one create a CustomerAccessToken securely?

Comment: I have the emails of the Customers (via the Customer Liquid class), but I do not have their passwords.

Thus I considered using a Javascript prompt and submitting of a hashed version of their password.

But is this secure?
Would you know of any way to do it on the server / administrator side?

Comment: It really depends on what it is that you are trying to accomplish. This is wide and broad subject. Take a look at the API tutorials. For server side you can look at the supported libraries to get an idea of how to manage the administrative side.

Comment: I am customising a Shopify App, allowing users to edit their profiles. 
There is no direct Shopify form that allows direct editing of Customer fields, thus I started using GraphQL.

It fulfills what I need, but the creation of this CustomerAccessToken seems very risky on the client side.

Comment: You are building a public facing shopping cart? In their officially support library for apps (https://github.com/kevinhughes27/shopify-sinatra-app) they say only OAUTH is supported for customer authentication.

Comment: Yes, it is public-facing. Standard Shopify setup. Okay, I will take a look at OAUTH. I have been using a Private App so far and OAUTH seems to be only supported by Public Apps. Sorry to bother you so much but the Shopify forums are quite quiet. :(

Comment: Using Graph: https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android/#creating-a-customer-